# Is it possible send mail using j2me without webserver

Tags: java-me

I want to send mail using j2me application.

I searched in google. Most of the code have invokes the servlet or web server to send mail. I don't like to post data to webserver to send mail. I want my j2me app to send mail. If anybody knows, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah it's a lot of work, you'll need to implement SMTP/POP3 yourself over a `SocketConnection`.  But if you're implementing a full email client, then this is probably what you want to do (although there are many out there already, just search GetJar).